# Roll back changes in bit bucket repo and then re add those changes later on down the road

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have made some changes through repo at **Bitbucket**. you can see the changes made as below

**What I want to do is roll back some of those changes and keep the rest.**

**In the future I will like to add and commit those**

What command can I use to do such?

For instance if I was to roll back to the last one 0416f69, what command can I execute ? **Can it be done through tortoise git**

Later if I were to readd the changes back, what command can I use?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few options:

1. Do a git **[patch](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch)** from your changes and later **[apply](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply)** them.
2. Checkout the lats required commit (Detached head) and then create a new branch form the point that you wish to keep. `git checkout <commit id>`
3. Do a git **[revert](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert)** on the unwanted commits
4. Backup your current work to a new branch and later on do a **[cherry pick](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick)** on the required commits.

Good luck and hope it was helpful for you.

Comment: this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide/323898#323898 is good explanation